# Disposing of a CD

Tags: disposal, genizah-storage

If a person owns a cd with pages of Torah in, halachically, can one dispose of the cd? and is there a difference between Ashkenazi and Mizrachi rules?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Aaron and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 0):

This essay, with references, concludes that it is permissible to erase or dispose of electronic files containing the name of God:

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/944731/jewish/Can-I-delete-Gds-name-on-a-computer-screen.htm